# Query over a varchar variable in a not stored script inside MySQL Workbench does not use the index?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a Table with a `VARCHAR(20)` as not unique index. If I declare a variable for it with `SET @varname = "XYZ"` the index is not used.

I tried to change `""` to `''`,
I tried to change `=` to `:=` in the SET statement,
I tried to use `=` and `LIKE` for my query.

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
  `ColumnID` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Time` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `indexed_varchar_field ` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,  
  UNIQUE KEY `ColumnID` (`ColumnID`),
  KEY `idx_varchar_field` (`indexed_varchar_field `)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20268516 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

SET @VAR_NAME = 'XYZ';
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE indexed_varchar_field = @VAR_NAME;
```

The actual table has more columns, the `indexed_varchar_field` is a serial number and I want to have all datasets from this machine. Without index it takes more than a minute, with index it takes less than a second.

If I try it without the variable it uses the index and is fast.

Comment: What does `EXLPAIN SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE indexed_varchar_field = @VAR_NAME;` yield? And how about `EXLPAIN SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE indexed_varchar_field = 'XYZ';`?

Comment: I am puzzled by 'I want to have all datasets from this machine' can you clarify please.

Comment: The explain statement:
# id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'table_name', NULL, 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '1', '100.00', 'Using where'

Comment: @P.Salmon The varchar is the serial number field of my device that is reporting data to this table.  

The 'I want to have all datasets from this machine' is more or less the verbal description for the select statement.